# What does "latter-day entries" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> What if figures like
>   Gandhi, Martin Luther
>   King, Jr., or Lech Wałesa
>   had been more
>    prominent parts of our
>    political history and not
>    the **latter-day** **entries** –
>    **thanks** **in** **part** **to** **classic**
>   **India** – **to** **it** **that** **they**
>   **have** **been**? Would a 
>   doctrine of divine right of kings have developed,
>   and all that followed in
>    reaction to it, had there
>    not been already in place
>    an equally absolute and 
>   competing theory of the
>    divine right of popes – as 
>   secular rulers

I'm being challenged by my teacher as to what the above text means. It's not his own writting but I'm guessing it's an excerpt from a book or something. I wish I had any more context to help with decoding its meaning. What baffles me most is the part in bold. I understand **latter-day** to mean contemporary or modern, but what does **entry** mean? I looked it up and none of the definitions could help make a straight sentence. I also don't understand the **to** **it** **that** **they** **have** **been** part, it what and they who?

I'll be grateful to anyone who can help.

Comment: I take “latter-day entries” to mean recent additions (to the canonical list of Important Historic Figures).  What “classic India” has to do with it, I cannot say.

Answer (score 2):

It means "Entries to our political history".

If you omit part of the sentence it makes more sense:

> What if figures like Gandhi, Martin Luther King, Jr., or Lech Wałesa had been more prominent parts of our
>   political history and not the latter-day entries to it that they have
>   been?

The "to it" means "to our political history".

This "aside" inserted in the middle of the sentence

> – thanks in part to classic India –

breaks up its flow.

Comment: You might add, wow, what a bad sentence!  Why not, "What if latter-day figures like Gandhi, Martin Luther King Jr., and Lech Walesa had been prominent in our earlier history?"  No doubt there are even better ways to put it.

Comment: @JiveDadson I take the point to be less that these people lived recently than that they were not mentioned much until recently.  Gandhi died well before I was born, but I rarely heard his name until the movie.